# shifting all rows from row no 3 to row no 2 (upward) breaks the formulas in all rows in XSSF sheet using POI java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Row number 1 is the header row. Shifting all rows (approx 100 plus) upward from row 3 to row 2 using POI 4.1.2 or 5.0.0 converts the formula to plain text.

```java
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    
    sheet.shiftRows(headerRow + 2, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
```

I expect the formulas to work properly post removing the second row.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. There was bugs with formulas when using `shiftRows`, but fixed since version 4.1.2. Would need the `*.xlsx` file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you look at [History of Changes](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html), there was fixed bugs with shifting formulas since version 5.0.0 too. So what happens if you try using current stable version 5.2.3? If that not solves the problem, we need the `*.xlsx`file for further investigation.

Comment: thanks @AxelRichter, please send me your email id so I can share the xlsx file, my email id is mhetrasaditya@gmail.com

Comment: No, that's not the way. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -> You create the simplest file where the issue occurs and either you provide the data and formulas in your question as text (best) or you upload it somewhere where all participants can download it (if too much data to show as text in the question).

Comment: hi @AxelRichter, it worked post upgrading to poi 5.2.3, and commons-io to 2.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading POI to 5.2.3 and commons-io to 2.11.0, it worked, thanks @AxelRichter.